# Evaluate $\int \frac{dx}{x(x-1)^3(x-2)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate $$I=\int \frac{dx}{x(x-1)^3(x-2)^2}$$ without using tedious partial fractions.

My Try:

we have $$1=\left((x-1)-(x-2)\right)^2$$ So
 $$=\int \frac{\left((x-1)-(x-2)\right)^2dx}{x(x-1)^3(x-2)^2}$$ So

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{x(x-1)(x-2)^2}+\int \frac{dx}{x(x-1)^3}-2\int \frac{dx}{x(x-1)^2(x-2)} $$

any clue here?

Comment: You will have to do partial fractions looks like

Comment: Also the integration is split within many terms, and so it seems evident that it is first integrated via partial fractions, and then to its respective antiderivatives

Comment: By *"without using **tedious** partial fractions"*, do you mean that you can use partial fractions only if its application is easy, or that you cannot use it at all?

Comment: If you find tedious doing partial fractions (and I agree with you) you can always make others do it for you and pretend to have done them by yourself :)  https://www.symbolab.com/solver/partial-fractions-calculator/partial%20fractions%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5Cleft(x-1%5Cright)%5E%7B3%7D%5Cleft(x-2%5Cright)%5E%7B2%7D%7D

Comment: If someone thinks that using web site to do partial fraction is cheating, my opinion is that also use calculator to to $23.708^{\frac{e}{\pi}}$ is cheating :)

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the labour a little by writing

$\dfrac{1}{x(x-1)^3(x-2)^2} = \dfrac{(1-x+x^2)+x(x-1)}{x(x-1)^3(x-2)^2}$

$=\dfrac{x(x-2)^2-(x-1)^3}{x(x-1)^3(x-2)^2} + \dfrac{1}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^2}$

$=\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^3} -  \dfrac{1}{x(x-2)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^2(x-2)^2}$

$=\dfrac{1}{(x-1)^3}- \dfrac{1}{x(x-2)^2}+ \dfrac{1}{(x-1)^2}+\dfrac{1}{(x-2)^2}+2 \left[\dfrac{1}{x-1} - \dfrac{1}{x-2} \right]$

If you wish you can further decompose $\dfrac{1}{x(x-2)^2}= \dfrac{1}{(x-2)^2}+\dfrac{1}{2} \left[\dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{x-2} \right]$

This expression can be readily integrated.